# Как я могу получать смс сообщения со своего номера телефона и выводить их куда-нибудь c помощью Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sms

Заинтересовал такой вопрос: могу ли я как-нибудь привязать несколько мобильных номеров к какому-то скрипту на компьютере, с помощью которого я смогу отлавливать СМСки, поступающие на номер? Может библиотека какая-нибудь есть на python?

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного, но Ваш вопрос слишком мало конкретики содержит. Если в общем то Вам необходим либо ПК с возможностью работы в мобильной сети (с возможностью установить симку и совершать вызовы / работу с смс) и сим карты с номерами которые вам надо привязаться и взимодействовать с модемом как с устройством или аккаунт у смс провайдера и взаимодействие с ним через tcp/http. Конкретнее все завиист от Вас, Вашего ПК, Ваших мобильных операторов итд. Библиотеки тоже есть по крайней мере я сталкивался с [Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python)

Comment: Есть сервис [онлансим](https://onlinesim.ru), у них есть открытый апи, возможно это то что вам нужно.